# can't go directly from fragment 1 to fragment 3 and fragment tabs are not working properly

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I am creating a layout like WhatsApp and I have used viewPager2. It is swiping perfectly but when I click on a specific tab it does not go there. and if I click tabs from right to left it's moving but from left to right it does not move.
I tried so many solution but nothing seems to work.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Camera"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Chats"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Status"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Calls"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager2 viewPager = (ViewPager2) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });

    viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
            tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(position));
        }
    });
}
```

}

pagerAdapter:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

public PagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
    super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
    switch(position) {
        case 0:
            CameraFragment cameraFragment = new CameraFragment();
            return cameraFragment;
        case 1:
            ChatsFragment chatsFragment = new ChatsFragment();
            return chatsFragment;
        case 2:
            StatusFragment statusFragment = new StatusFragment();
            return statusFragment;
        case 3:
            CallsFragment callsFragment = new CallsFragment();
            return callsFragment;
        default:
            return new ChatsFragment();
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 4;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TabLayoutMediator` instade of `OnTabSelectedListener`

Make changes as below

```
ArrayList<String> title = new ArrayList<>(); // add this before onCreate Method
//---------After onCreate
title.add("Camera");
title.add("Camera");
title.add("Camera");
title.add("Camera"); 

new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager, (tab, position) -> tab.setText(title.get(position))).attach(); //title.get(position) -> here add arraylist of title.
```

and remove these below codes

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });

    viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
            tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(position));
        }
    });
```

Comment: you are a lifesaver man. I can't upvote you because of my score but thank you so much.

Comment: @Dua let's checkmark my answer as an answer. Otherwise, other devs will answer your question.

Comment: @M DEV how can I add default tab in it? like I want second tab to show when I open app

Comment: @Dua please explain in details.

Comment: It is solved . I added following code :    
        tabLayout.setScrollPosition(1,0f,true);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);